# Perforce: How to cancel a Sync operation?

Tags: perforce

When you are using P4 Windows client, you may cancel a long running sync operation by pressing the red cancel button.

I am trying hard to find out what the operation for that is in the command line accordingly?

Your help would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CTL+C?

Control-C usually kills any console process.

Comment: This works for me.  It will stop the sync after the current file is done (I think).